# Clear Android Carousel view

Tags: android, performance

I'v created an app to display images on a carousel. App contains two buttons, Which are promotion and event, and once I click the event button, images are loaded and I can view the carousel. Then if I click the promotion button, images are display on carousel, too.

But when I click the event button again, the images are loaded with the images loaded before.
How to overcome this problem. I want to clear carousel view once it's loaded before I click  the button again.

Comment: Please provide more information such as some code. Otherwise we have nooo idea what's wrong. NOooo idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your view to a ViewGroup object (assuming it is a ViewGroup), and call removeAllViews:

```
((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
```

Comment: This is works for event button. But not for other button. when click promotion button images are loaded over & over. thank for your reply

Answer (score -1):

you can use setVisible(false) , the clear the view .